# Adding new column and index to a table with a billion records

Tags: oracle, indexing, conditional-statements

I want to add a new column into to a table with billion records. To speed the up the select statement, I need to add a new index which will contain this column and the PK column.

1. How long will it take to add a new index in a billion records table?
2. The new column for example [Field], the value will be 0,1,2,9.
   Most of record's will be 9. In the select condition 
   Field=0 or Field=1 or Field=2 will be used, but the Field=9 will not be used.

   for example in the a billion records table ,

   - Field with value 0 records:100,000;
   - Field with value 1 records:100,000;
   - Field with value 2 records:100,000;
   - Field with value 9 records:a billion-300,000
3. Should I create index on the column?
   If not, the select sql that contain the condition
   Field=0  will be too slow to return results?

Answer (score 1):

If most of the values are 9's then you can avoid including them in the index with:

```
create index my_index on my_table (case column_name when 9 then null else column_name end);
```

Then query on ...

```
select ...
from   ...
where  case column_name when 9 then null else column_name end = 2
```

... for example.

The time taken will be the time required to scan the entire table, then sort the 300,000 records that will go in the index. Faster with a parallel index build, of course.